# Docker Error: Unable to write to the database. Exit code: 1

Tags: docker

When trying to start Docker I keep getting this error:

> Unable to write to the database. Exit code: 1    at
>   Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   247    at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Restart(Settings
>   settings) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   182    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   47    at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action,
>   Object[] parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   145

I've tried almost every trick I can think of. First I upgraded from Windows 10 Home to Pro for Hyper-V. Then I uninstalled Tunnelbear because I heard that can be a problem. I don't have Windows Companion installed (a common fix to this issue is uninstalling it), and I have installed it and run it as administrator. I've also tried this [fix](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-1-12-for-windows-10-is-not-working/16647/3) to no avail. If anyone can help I'd be most grateful.